# PHP script GD library memory problem

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload, imagecreatefrompng

On my site I allow users to upload 6 images max size of 5MB. They must be in format either gif,jpg/jpeg. Most images users seem to upload are about 2MB roughly (1006188 bytes) and height:1536 pixels by width:2048 pixels so quite big (especially if trying to resize as well).

I then have two directories (large_img and small_img) on server. In large_img I move the uploaded file into there. I then re-size that image from that large_img directory using GD library to a thumbnail sized (100 height by 100 width) and move that into small_img.

I have been getting an error occasionally

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 80740352) (tried to allocate 14592 bytes)
```

maximum memory allowed on my apache server is 64MB . So theres some sort of problem with my code ie taking a few couple chunks of this 64MB and not releasing it for some reason.

Here is my code to take image and resize it. I have provided it for the first image out of the 6 and have not included error checks here as to much to copy and paste:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile_0']['tmp_name'], $move_file_to_directoryname_large))
{
        $n_width=100;$n_height=100; /*specify height/width of thumbnail image to be*/

        if($_FILES["uploadedfile_0"]["type"]=="image/gif")
        {
                    $im=imagecreatefromgif($move_file_to_directoryname_large);
                    if(!$im)
                    {
                            /*error could occur here if image was say named .gif but was another type like .jpg casing file type error*/
                            $image_resize_error++; 
                            $array_error_msg_resize[$image_resize_error]="<p class='form_error_messages'>&#8226; An unfixable error occurred with your image ('<span class='standard_span'> " .$_FILES['uploadedfile_0']['name']." </span>').</p>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $width=imagesx($im); $height=imagesy($im);
                            $newsmallerimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);                 
                            imagecopyresized($newsmallerimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);
                            $move_file_to_directoryname_small=$target_path_small.$newfilename;
                            if(function_exists("imagegif"))
                            {
                                    imagegif($newsmallerimage,$move_file_to_directoryname_small); 
                                    $images_db_small[0]=substr_replace($move_file_to_directoryname_small, "", 0, 24);
                            }
                            /*frees image from memory */
                            imagedestroy($newsmallerimage);
                    }
            }
            if($_FILES["uploadedfile_0"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
            {
                            $im=imagecreatefromjpeg($move_file_to_directoryname_large); /*create from image stored in directory specified when moving from /tmp*/
                            if(!$im)
                            {
                                    /*error could occur here if image was say named .gif but was another type like .jpg casing file type error*/
                                    $image_resize_error++; 
                                    $array_error_msg_resize[$image_resize_error]="<p class='form_error_messages'>&#8226; An unfixable error occurred with your image ('<span class='standard_span'> " .$_FILES['uploadedfile_0']['name']." </span>').</p>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    $width=imagesx($im);/*Original picture width is stored*/$height=imagesy($im);/*Original picture height is stored*/
                                    $newsmallerimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);                 
                                    $imagecopyresized($newsmallerimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);
                                    $move_file_to_directoryname_small=$target_path_small.$newfilename;
                                    if(function_exists("imagejpeg"))
                                    {
                                            imagejpeg($newsmallerimage,$move_file_to_directoryname_small); 
                                            $images_db_small[0]=substr_replace($move_file_to_directoryname_small, "", 0, 24);
                                    }
                                    /*frees image from memory */
                                    imagedestroy($newsmallerimage);
                            }
                }
}
```

Heres my php.ini settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 30M
max_execution_time = 120 
max_file_uploads = 6
memory_limit=128M
```

Something in script is eating the memory up. The error occurred mentioned above occurs at this part of code `$im=imagecreatefromjpeg($move_file_to_directoryname_large);`if its jpeg photo or imagecreatefromgif() if its gif photo format

I am releasing memory by destroying image `$imagedestroy($newsmallerimage);`

Note this same code if() statement is repeated for other 5 images just named ['uploadedfile_1'] ...2 etc

Any suggestions perhaps read the files into memory using file_get_contents or the GD library. I know that GD holds the entire image uncompressed in memory which could be the problem.
Thanks guys

Comment: Any reason you do `function_exists('imagejpeg')`? Your script would have died at the `imagecreatefromjpeg()` if GD wasn't install or jpeg support wasn't enabled.

Comment: @Marc B - not really any reason I dont need that if(function_exists()) part can get rid of that cant I and take the code inside of it outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not freeing `$im`, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: so how do I free it, does imagedestroy() not do that?

Comment: @daza: you're only destroyed the resized images. `$im` is the original image and you don't do a destroy on that.

Comment: spot on I did not destroyimage($im). only was imagedestroy($newsmallerimage) no wonder I was running out of memory and that was what the error log was pointing to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the image you are creating via `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

in `if()` condition add line,

```
imagedestroy($im);
```

like this,

```
if(!$im)
{
    $image_resize_error++; 
    $array_error_msg_resize[$image_resize_error]="<p class='form_error_messages'>&#8226; An unfixable error occurred with your image ('<span class='standard_span'> " .$_FILES['uploadedfile_0']['name']." </span>').</p>";
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```